# How works "require" after "export default" in EC6?

Tags: javascript, iec61131-3

Following a tutorial I found this chunk of code in a file:

```
export default require ('knex') ({
   client : 'mysql';
   connection : {
      host : 'localhost',
      user : 'root',
      password: '',
      database : 'graph',
      charset : 'utf8',
   }
});
```

This file is being imported in another as :

```
import Knex from './knex'
```

When I run the app I get this error

```
Unexpected token (1:20)
export default knex require ('knex') ({
    client : 'mysql';
    connection : {
        host : 'localhost',
    }
})
```

I want to fix this but I don't understand how `require` works when is preceded for `export default`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your `export default require` is not valid. Try this instead:

```
export default {
      client : 'mysql';
      connection : {
        host : 'localhost',
        user : 'root',
        password: '',
        database : 'graph',
        charset : 'utf8',
   }
```

It exports an objet that you can later import with `import myObj from './myfile'`.

Comment: I got a similar error export default {
        client : 'mysql';
        connection : {
                host : 'localhost',
                user : 'root',

Comment: It's working now `export default require` works the problem was a semicolon `client : 'mysql';` sorry and thanks!